# Can't change dconf-entry with GSettings

Tags: javascript, gio, gnome-shell, gjs

I'm currently building a simple application on [Gjs](http://live.gnome.org/Gjs), which should change the background-image of my gnome-shell. A solution on how this can be done using the `gsettings`-tool can be found [here](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-August/402603.html).

Since I want to build a desktop-application around it, I want to change the `org.gnome.desktop.background.picture-uri`-key by using Gio's [`GSettings`-class](http://www.roojs.com/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/gjs/Gio.Settings.html). But using the `set_X()`-method does not change the value of the key.

This is my code to change the gsettings value:

```
var gio = imports.gi.Gio;

// Get the GSettings-object for the background-schema:
var background = new gio.Settings({schema: "org.gnome.desktop.background"});

// Read the current Background-Image:
print( "Current Background-Image: "+background.get_string("picture-uri") );

if (background.is_writable("picture-uri")){
    // Set a new Background-Image (should show up immediately):
    if (background.set_string("picture-uri", "file:///path/to/some/pic.jpg")){
        print("Success!");
    }
    else throw "Couldn't set the key!";
} else throw "The key is not writable";
```

Reading the value does work as expected, the `is_writable()`-method returns `true` and the `set_string()`-method also returns `true`.

I have checked that I'm not in "delay-apply" mode and the key has a `GVariantType` of string, so the `set_string()`-method should work.

Using the normal `gsettings` command-line tool (as explained in the linked post) works just fine.

I can't figure out what the problem is, is there any place I can look for logs or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After not getting any responses here I [asked the same question on the gjs-mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/javascript-list/2012-April/msg00000.html).

It turned out that the writes to dconf were not yet on the disk when my script exited, so they were never really applied.

The solution was to call the [`g_settings_sync()` function](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/GSettings.html#g-settings-sync) ([JsDoc](http://www.roojs.com/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/gjs/Gio.Settings.html#Gio.Settings-method-sync)) right after the `set_string()` function, to ensure that all writes had finished.

```
if (background.set_string("picture-uri", "file:///path/to/some/pic.jpg")){
    gio.Settings.sync()
    print("Success!");
}
```

Thanks to Johan Dahlin and [his answer](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/javascript-list/2012-April/msg00001.html).

Comment: I've been breaking my head over this problem since yesterday and am so glad to finally have found the solution. Thanks!