# Edit gsettings in a C++

Tags: c++, glib, gnome, gio, gsettings

I'm trying to edit a gsetting through a C++ program.
I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582082/reading-gsettings-from-c-program) and I'm able to get the value. If I try to set it (using `set_uint` method), change seems to be made (if I re-read it shows the new value) but, if I check manually, it is not so. Do I have to apply the edits? Or what else?

Example code:

```
#include <giomm/settings.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Settings> colorSetting = 
                  Gio::Settings::create("org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color");
    Glib::ustring tempKey = "night-light-temperature";

    //Works!
    cout<<colorSetting->get_uint(tempKey)<<endl;

    //Seems to work
    colorSetting->set_uint(tempKey, (unsigned) 2300);

    //Reads new value correctly
    cout<<colorSetting->get_uint(tempKey)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show code - we aren't telephatic. A [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best.

Comment: @tambre Sorry, added now!

Comment: Much better, good job.

Comment: @tambre There's a magic tag for MCVE, `[MCVE]`, the result is: [MCVE]

Comment: @Jonas Thank you! I wasn't aware of that. For all this time I've been manually linking the [MCVE] page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your program is exiting almost immediately after setting the value, it’s likely that the asynchronous write machinery in `GSettings` has not written the new value to disk by the time your program exits.

Try adding a `g_settings_sync()` call before exiting (I don’t know how it’s bound in `giomm`, but that’s what the call is in C). From [the documentation for `g_settings_sync()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GSettings.html#g-settings-sync):

> Writes made to a `GSettings` are handled asynchronously. For this reason, it is very unlikely that the changes have it to disk by the time `g_settings_set()` returns.

To be clear, a `g_settings_sync()` call should not normally be necessary; it’s only necessary here because you’re not running a main loop.

See also: [G_Settings apply changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778013/g-settings-apply-changes) and [Can't change dconf-entry with GSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985140/cant-change-dconf-entry-with-gsettings), which cover the same issue but from the perspective of C and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I've simply added that (exact) call before return and changes were made.